# Highcharts setData on pie chart not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am displaying a pie chart using the Highchart library. I have two sets of data I want to show, and I toggle between the two sets every 5 seconds indefinitely. When I load the initial set of data, the chart displays as it should. And when I load the second set of data (using `setData`), the chart changes as it should. However, all subsequent calls to `setData` seem to do nothing. I would expect the chart to change again and again corresponding to the new data. But nothing happens, and there are no errors logged in the console. What could I be doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var chart24HoursTop5;
var lastSet = 1;
var set1 = [{
    "seconds": 754,
    "y": 754,
    "downtime": "00:05:07",
    "siteNumber": "13",
    "siteName": "Preston",
    "name": "Preston",
    "motorolaNumber": "SZ092C113",
    "system": "SZ Quantar",
    "channels": "5",
    "towerOwner": "Wynn Communications",
    "shelterOwner": "Wynn Communications",
    "equipmentOwner": "DPS",
    "latitude": "35.724833",
    "longitude": "-95.988333",
    "color": "#348AA7"
}, {
    "seconds": 20,
    "y": 20,
    "downtime": "00:00:20",
    "siteNumber": "29",
    "siteName": "Bakers Peak",
    "name": "Bakers Peak",
    "motorolaNumber": "SZ092C129",
    "system": "SZ Quantar",
    "channels": "5",
    "towerOwner": "FBI",
    "shelterOwner": "DPS",
    "equipmentOwner": "DPS",
    "latitude": "34.839722",
    "longitude": "-98.803333",
    "color": "#ffa600"
}, {
    "seconds": 19,
    "y": 19,
    "downtime": "00:00:19",
    "siteNumber": "30",
    "siteName": "Walters",
    "name": "Walters",
    "motorolaNumber": "SZ092C130",
    "system": "SZ Quantar",
    "channels": "5",
    "towerOwner": "Cotton Electric",
    "shelterOwner": "DPS",
    "equipmentOwner": "DPS",
    "latitude": "34.358583",
    "longitude": "-98.321583",
    "color": "#cb5464"
}, {
    "seconds": 12,
    "y": 12,
    "downtime": "00:00:12",
    "siteNumber": "69",
    "siteName": "Hominy",
    "name": "Hominy",
    "motorolaNumber": "SZ092C169",
    "system": "P25 GTR",
    "channels": "",
    "towerOwner": "Grand River Dam Authority",
    "shelterOwner": "Grand River Dam Authority",
    "equipmentOwner": "GRDA",
    "latitude": "36.4",
    "longitude": "-96.4863888888889",
    "color": "#82F2C0"
}];
var set2 = [{
    "seconds": 691,
    "y": 691,
    "downtime": "691 Sec",
    "siteNumber": "13",
    "siteName": "Preston 2",
    "name": "Preston 2",
    "motorolaNumber": "SZ092C113",
    "system": "SZ Quantar",
    "channels": "5",
    "towerOwner": "Wynn Communications",
    "shelterOwner": "Wynn Communications",
    "equipmentOwner": "DPS",
    "latitude": "35.724833",
    "longitude": "-95.988333",
    "color": "#348AA7"
}, {
    "seconds": 10,
    "y": 10,
    "downtime": "10 Sec",
    "siteNumber": "29",
    "siteName": "Bakers Peak 2",
    "name": "Bakers Peak 2",
    "motorolaNumber": "SZ092C129",
    "system": "SZ Quantar",
    "channels": "5",
    "towerOwner": "FBI",
    "shelterOwner": "DPS",
    "equipmentOwner": "DPS",
    "latitude": "34.839722",
    "longitude": "-98.803333",
    "color": "#ffa600"
}, {
    "seconds": 1,
    "y": 1,
    "downtime": "1 Sec",
    "siteNumber": "30",
    "siteName": "Walters 2",
    "name": "Walters 2",
    "motorolaNumber": "SZ092C130",
    "system": "SZ Quantar",
    "channels": "5",
    "towerOwner": "Cotton Electric",
    "shelterOwner": "DPS",
    "equipmentOwner": "DPS",
    "latitude": "34.358583",
    "longitude": "-98.321583",
    "color": "#cb5464"
}, {
    "seconds": 5,
    "y": 5,
    "downtime": "5 Sec",
    "siteNumber": "69",
    "siteName": "Hominy 2",
    "name": "Hominy 2",
    "motorolaNumber": "SZ092C169",
    "system": "P25 GTR",
    "channels": "",
    "towerOwner": "Grand River Dam Authority",
    "shelterOwner": "Grand River Dam Authority",
    "equipmentOwner": "GRDA",
    "latitude": "36.4",
    "longitude": "-96.4863888888889",
    "color": "#82F2C0"
}];

$(document).ready(function () {
    var optionsFor24HoursTop5 = {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Last 24 Hours'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.downtime}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}: {point.downtime}'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'DropSum',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: set1
        }]
    };
    chart24HoursTop5 = Highcharts.chart("chartContainer", optionsFor24HoursTop5);
    setTimeout(changeData, 5000);
});

function changeData() {
    if (lastSet == 1) {
        chart24HoursTop5.series[0].setData(set2);
        lastSet = 2;
    } else {
        chart24HoursTop5.series[0].setData(set1);
        lastSet = 1;
    }
```

And here is a fully working jsFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/ksd8gjec/23/

You'll notice in the example that the chart displays initially, and then 5 seconds later, the data changes and is reflected in the chart display. However, the data changes again every 5 seconds, and none of those changes are reflected in the chart display. Why won't Highcharts show the updated data after the first change?

Answer (score 0):

This does appear to be some sort of bug(?), but a workaround seems to be to specify that points should not be updated when setting the data. For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zowcy513/)):

```
function changeData() {
  if (lastSet == 1){
    // The fourth parameter makes or breaks the update
    chart24HoursTop5.series[0].setData(set2, true, true, false);
    lastSet = 2;
  } else {
    // The fourth parameter makes or breaks the update
    chart24HoursTop5.series[0].setData(set1, true, true, false);
    lastSet = 1;
  }
  setTimeout(changeData, 5000);
}
```

This does mean that there is no animation, as the points are scraped and new points are created. It does however appear that it is this updating of points that seems to stop the update from happening at all, so hopefully the main issue can be resolved as well.

Answer (score 0):

For performace Highcharts mutate the original data array, which causes that variables `set1` and `set2` are the same after the first update.

The solution can be to return the data by function:

```
function set1() {
    return [...];
}

function set2() {
    return [...];
}

function changeData() {
    if (lastSet == 1) {
        chart24HoursTop5.series[0].setData(set2());
        lastSet = 2;
    } else {
        chart24HoursTop5.series[0].setData(set1());
        lastSet = 1;
    }
    setTimeout(changeData, 2000);
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0smxjLac/